# OpenPAM and Linux PAM compatibility

Tags: c, security, unix, authentication, pam

I'm looking to implement a Pluggable Authentication Module that is relatively portable across Solaris, Mac OSX, BSD, and Linux operating systems.

The choices:

- [Linux PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org)
- [Open PAM](http://www.openpam.org)

I've found a few [sources](http://www.redhat.com/archives/pam-list/2003-October/msg00006.html) (2003) that lean towards Linux PAM being the better solution.
However no mention of portability.  It seems OpenPAM is used more widely, so would be the obvious choice.

Has anyone had any real life experience in attempting to create a portable-ish solution?